# How to measure spin-spin correlation in Heisenberg Model?

Tags: quantum-spin, spin-statistics, spin-models

How to measure the spin-spin correlation in Heisenberg Model? I use the QMC method, working on 2d case.

Comment: Possibly related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169442/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to measure the spin-spin correlation in a Monte Carlo simulation of the Ising model?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169442/)